# Is there a way to find if browser pop-up window opened with window.open had the parameter 'scrollbars=yes'?

Tags: javascript, window.open

Is there a way to find if browser pop-up window opened with window.open had the parameter 'scrollbars=yes'? 
I need to run specific code depending on scrollbars being on or off, meaning they might not be showing but they are still on.

Even if there is not general browser solution, any help for IE will be great.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

I would try finding the code that handles the `window.open` and saving a global variable. Then you can access the global variable by using `window.parent`

Comment: I just have thought of the same thing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.scrollbars.visible
```

This should return true or false.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollbars